# How to crete a slideshow in jquery with different size of images

Tags: jquery, image, slideshow, resize

I want to create a slideshow using jquery. But i have different size of images. Please suggest me how do i create slideshow which changes its dimension depending on the images?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that the colorbox plugin does a good job of this.

http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

Answer (score 1):

There are many examples given at

http://www.dynamicwp.net/articles-and-tutorials/top-20-jquery-slideshow-and-image-gallery-tutorials/

Please check these examples. Pick the best suited for your requirement.
If we know the plugin you are using it would be easier to help. Have you already selected any?

Comment: Thanks Rajesh. But in this, i could find slideshow with same size of images, not with different sixe.

Comment: At following link there is a slideshow written using java script (not jquery) please let me know if it serves your requirement. I will provide the source code in that case.  http://spepl.com/gallery.htm

Comment: Yes Rajesh. Its exactly the same what i wanted!

Answer (score 1):

- http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/
- http://fancybox.net/
- http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html
- http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/
- http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

Answer (score 0):

The code you wanted is as follows:
Add following code to html file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var rotator1 = {
    path:   'Images/',
    id:   'imgsite',
    speed:  3000, // default 4500
    images: ["image1_big.jpg", "image2_medium.jpg", "image3_small.jpg"],
    bTrans: true // ie win filter
}

function initRotator() {
    mts_Rotator.setup(rotator1);
}

mts_Event.add( window, 'load', initRotator);
</script>
```

The scripts needed are as below

```
    var mts_Event = {

    add: function(obj, etype, fp, cap) {
        cap = cap || false;
        if (obj.addEventListener) obj.addEventListener(etype, fp, cap);
        else if (obj.attachEvent) obj.attachEvent("on" + etype, fp);
    }, 

    remove: function(obj, etype, fp, cap) {
        cap = cap || false;
        if (obj.removeEventListener) obj.removeEventListener(etype, fp, cap);
        else if (obj.detachEvent) obj.detachEvent("on" + etype, fp);
    }, 

    DOMit: function(e) { 
        e = e? e: window.event; // e IS passed when using attachEvent though ...
        if (!e.target) e.target = e.srcElement;
        if (!e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault = function () { e.returnValue = false; return false; }
        if (!e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation = function () { e.cancelBubble = true; }
        return e;
    },

    getTarget: function(e) {
        e = mts_Event.DOMit(e); var tgt = e.target; 
        if (tgt.nodeType != 1) tgt = tgt.parentNode; // safari...
        return tgt;
    }

}

function addLoadEvent(func) {
    var oldQueue = window.onload? window.onload: function() {};
    window.onload = function() {
        oldQueue();
        func();
    }
}

/*************************************************************************
*************************************************************************/

// arguments: image id, rotation speed, path to images (optional), 
// new (optional) arguments: for transitions, mouse events and random rotation 
function mts_Rotator(id, speed, path, bTrans, bMouse, bRand) {
    var imgObj = document.getElementById(id); 
    if (!imgObj) { // in case name, not id attached to image
        imgObj = document.images[id];
        if (!imgObj) return;
        imgObj.id = id;
    }
    this.id = id; this.speed = speed || 4500; // default speed of rotation
    this.path = path || "";  this.bRand = bRand;
    this.ctr = 0; this.timer = 0; this.imgs = []; 
    this._setupLink(imgObj, bMouse);
    this.bTrans = bTrans && typeof imgObj.filters != 'undefined';
    var index = mts_Rotator.col.length; mts_Rotator.col[index] = this;
    this.animString = "mts_Rotator.col[" + index + "]";
}

mts_Rotator.col = []; // hold instances
mts_Rotator.resumeDelay = 400; // onmouseout resume rotation after delay

// mouse events pause/resume
mts_Rotator.prototype._setupLink = function(imgObj, bMouse) { 
    if ( imgObj.parentNode && imgObj.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'a' ) {
        var parentLink = this.parentLink = imgObj.parentNode;
        if (bMouse) {
            mts_Event.add(parentLink, 'mouseover', mts_Rotator.pause);
            mts_Event.add(parentLink, 'mouseout', mts_Rotator.resume);
        }
    }
}

// so instance can be retrieved by id (as well as by looping through col)
mts_Rotator.getInstanceById = function(id) {
    var len = mts_Rotator.col.length, obj;
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        obj = mts_Rotator.col[i];
        if (obj.id && obj.id == id ) {
            return obj;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

mts_Rotator.prototype.on_rotate = function() {}

mts_Rotator.prototype.addImages = function() { // preloads images
    var img;
    for (var i=0; arguments[i]; i++) {
        img = new Image();
        img.src = this.path + arguments[i];
        this.imgs[this.imgs.length] = img;
    }
}

mts_Rotator.prototype.rotate = function() {
    clearTimeout(this.timer); this.timer = null;
    var imgObj = document.getElementById(this.id);
    if ( this.bRand ) {
        this.setRandomCtr();
    } else {
        if (this.ctr < this.imgs.length-1) this.ctr++;
        else this.ctr = 0;
    }
    if ( this.bTrans ) {
        this.doImageTrans(imgObj);
    } else {
        imgObj.src = this.imgs[this.ctr].src;
    }
    this.swapAlt(imgObj); this.prepAction(); this.on_rotate();
    this.timer = setTimeout( this.animString + ".rotate()", this.speed);   
}

mts_Rotator.prototype.setRandomCtr = function() {
    var i = 0, ctr;
    do { 
        ctr = Math.floor( Math.random() * this.imgs.length );
        i++; 
    } while ( ctr == this.ctr && i < 6 )// repeat attempts to get new image, if necessary
    this.ctr = ctr;
}

mts_Rotator.prototype.doImageTrans = function(imgObj) {
    imgObj.style.filter = 'blendTrans(duration=1)';
    if (imgObj.filters.blendTrans) imgObj.filters.blendTrans.Apply();
    imgObj.src = this.imgs[this.ctr].src;
    imgObj.filters.blendTrans.Play(); 
}

mts_Rotator.prototype.swapAlt = function(imgObj) {
    if ( !imgObj.setAttribute ) return;
    if ( this.alt && this.alt[this.ctr] ) {
        imgObj.setAttribute('alt', this.alt[this.ctr]);
    }
    if ( this.title && this.title[this.ctr] ) {
        imgObj.setAttribute('title', this.title[this.ctr]);
    }
}

mts_Rotator.prototype.prepAction = function() {
    if ( this.actions && this.parentLink && this.actions[this.ctr] ) {
        if ( typeof this.actions[this.ctr] == 'string' ) {
            this.parentLink.href = this.actions[this.ctr];
        } else if ( typeof this.actions[this.ctr] == 'function' ) {
            // to execute function when linked image clicked 
            // passes id used to uniquely identify instance  
            // retrieve it using the mts_Rotator.getInstanceById function 
            // so any property of the instance could be obtained for use in the function 
            var id = this.id;
            this.parentLink.href = "javascript: void " + this.actions[this.ctr] + "('" + id + "')";
        } 
    }
}

mts_Rotator.prototype.showCaption = function() {
    if ( this.captions && this.captionId ) {
        var el = document.getElementById( this.captionId );
        if ( el && this.captions[this.ctr] ) {
            el.innerHTML = this.captions[this.ctr];
        }
    }
}

// Start rotation for all instances 
mts_Rotator.start = function() {
    var len = mts_Rotator.col.length, obj;
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        obj = mts_Rotator.col[i];
        if (obj && obj.id ) {
            clearTimeout( obj.timer ); obj.timer = null; 
            obj.timer = setTimeout( obj.animString + ".rotate()", obj.speed);
        }
    }
}

// Stop rotation for all instances 
mts_Rotator.stop = function() {
    var len = mts_Rotator.col.length, obj;
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        obj = mts_Rotator.col[i];
        if (obj ) { clearTimeout(obj.timer); obj.timer = null; }
    }
}

// for stopping/starting (onmouseover/out)
mts_Rotator.pause = function(e) {   
    e = mts_Event.DOMit(e);
    var id = e.target.id;
    var obj = mts_Rotator.getInstanceById(id);
    if ( obj ) { clearTimeout( obj.timer ); obj.timer = null; }
}

mts_Rotator.resume = function(e) {
    e = mts_Event.DOMit(e);
    var id = e.target.id;
    var obj = mts_Rotator.getInstanceById(id);
    if ( obj && obj.id ) {
        obj.timer = setTimeout( obj.animString + ".rotate()", mts_Rotator.resumeDelay );
    }
}

// calls constructor, addImages, adds actions, etc.
mts_Rotator.setup = function () {
    if (!document.getElementById) return;
    var i, j, rObj, r, imgAr, len;
    for (i=0; arguments[i]; i++) {
        rObj = arguments[i];
        r = new mts_Rotator(rObj.id, rObj.speed, rObj.path, rObj.bTrans, rObj.bMouse, rObj.bRand);
        try {
            imgAr = rObj.images; len = imgAr.length;
            for (j=0; j<len; j++) { r.addImages( imgAr[j] ); }
            if( rObj.num ) r.ctr = rObj.num; // for seq after random selection
            if ( rObj.actions && rObj.actions.length == len ) {
                r.addProp('actions', rObj.actions);
            }
            if ( rObj.alt && rObj.alt.length == len ) {
                r.addProp('alt', rObj.alt);
            }
            if ( rObj.title && rObj.title.length == len ) {
                r.addProp('title', rObj.title);
            }
            if ( rObj.captions ) {
                r.addProp('captions', rObj.captions);
                r.captionId = rObj.captionId;
                mts_Rotator.addRotateEvent(r, function (id) { 
                    return function() { mts_Rotator.getInstanceById(id).showCaption(); }
                }(rObj.id) ); // see Crockford js good parts pg 39
            }
        } catch (e) { 
            //alert(e.message); 
        }
    }
    mts_Rotator.start();
}

// add to on_rotate for specified instance (r)
// see usage above for captions
mts_Rotator.addRotateEvent = function( r, fp ) {
    var old_on_rotate = r.on_rotate;
    r.on_rotate = function() { old_on_rotate(); fp(); }
}

// for adding actions, alt, title
mts_Rotator.prototype.addProp = function(prop, ar) {
    if ( !this[prop] ) {
        this[prop] = [];
    }
    var len = ar.length; 
    for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {
        this[prop][ this[prop].length ] = ar[i]; 
    }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Reminder about licensing requirements
// OK to remove after purchasing a license or if using on a personal site.
function mts_checkAuth() {
}
mts_Event.add( window, 'load', mts_checkAuth);
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```